# Is it possible to receive Ctrl+Space from a bluetooth keyboard on Android?

Tags: android, android-input-method

When having a bluetooth (or otherwise external keyboard) on Android no events are sent to the application when pressing Ctrl+Space. Is it possible to receive key events from that key combination somehow?

Comment: How are you trying to get the events? `onKeyDown()`?

Comment: Yes, tried both `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyPreIme()`.